# Can't add first auto-renewable subscription to new app version

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to add my first Auto-renewable subscription to my app. As apple states here, I need to attach it to a new app version:

[image]

The problem is, when I try to follow that guide, I don't have ANY option for Auto-Renewable Subscriptions on my App review page:

[image]

There should be an option for `In-App Purchases and Subscriptions` to be added under the Build section, as stated [here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev1986a0e5c) under the submit an in-app purchase for the first time section.

[image]

My Auto-Renewable Subscription group is set up, with two subscriptions in it. All setup completely as far as I am aware. But for some reason, they both say: `Missing Metadata` which I suspect has something to do with it.

[image]

And finally, my Paid Applications contract is set to Active, as the app is a paid app that I am turning into a freemium app. So no idea what is going on here. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `App Store Connect > Your App > In App Purchase > Select your subscription`

Scroll to the bottom. You are likely missing the screenshot

[image]

Once you have the image there you can select it in your build.

Comment: I thought this too, but I already have the screenshot on my subscriptions.

Comment: Figured it out, it seems that you can save the screenshot before processing is completed, if you do this it seems like it will never finish processing, but it still shows the screenshot as uploaded, but it will be stuck on missing metadata.