# Can't fetch products from App Store Connect

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, storekit

I had everything working with Revenue Cat. Then my app got rejected for not loading subscriptions, which was odd because a previous built was rejected for wording on that same paywall.

I checked, and realised I suddenly can't fetch products in testFlight either. I can only see products in Xcode using the store kit configuration file.

I've found many issues like this online and everybody point to the same solutions (that seem to work for most), but here's what I tried so far:

1. Checked that all my agreements in App Store Connect are active
2. Checked that ids match between Xcode / revenue cat / App Store connect
3. Store kit config file is syncing with App Store Connect correctly
4. I removed revenue cat and used the store kit api directly to fetch products. The array of products is empty in all environments that don't have access to store kit config file.
5. Checked status of all subscriptions (all waiting for review -- as they were when the paywall worked)

Nothing seems to work...

Any suggestions? Many thanks

**Update:**

I found the problem, but I’m unsure what to do with it, so still need some help.

It turns out that because the app is iPhone-only and not a universal app, Store Kit won't fetch products when the app runs in compatibility mode. We identified that the App Store reviewer tested our iPhone app on an iPad. When we run the app on an iPhone, everything is fine.

We temporarily replaced Revenue Cat with calls directly from Store Kit, and when we try to fetch products on an iPad, we get an error:

```
Received error that does not have a corresponding StoreKit Error: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=500 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x3032769d0 {Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=301 "Invalid Status Code" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Status Code, AMSURL=https://amp-api.sandbox.apple.com/v1/catalog/gb/in-apps?additionalPlatforms=iphone&extend=kind&filter%5BappBundleId%5D=io.houseofmars.Pearla&filter%5BsubscriptionFamilyId%5D=21448567&l=en-GB&omit%5Bresource%5D=autos&platform=ipad&with=adHocOffers, AMSStatusCode=400, AMSServerPayload={
errors =     (
            {
        code = 40004;
        detail = "Parameter 'additionalPlatforms' is not allowed";
        id = 25T7JY2SONEPRPL5BY55CRBAGE;
        source =             {
            parameter = additionalPlatforms;
        };
        status = 400;
        title = "Invalid Parameter";
    }
);
```

}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Response status code is: 400}}}

If we temporarily allow iPad as a supported platform, the error disappears, and the products load correctly.

1. Our app is not designed to scale to iPad-size screens, so we can't enable iPad support.
2. There doesn’t seem to be a way to prevent apps from running in iPhone compatibility mode on iPads.
3. Our app is getting rejected due to reviewers being unable to get past the paywall.

Is there a way to enable in-app purchases to work for iPhone apps running on iPads?

** Update 2 **
So far, there doesn't seem to be a way around this issue. However, Apple's review team eventually approved our app after some explaining.

Note that if you have an iPhone only app, iPad users will be able to download it, but they will not be able to fetch products / subscriptions from the App Store and get past the paywall.

As of March 2024 there's no reliable way to detect if a user is in iPhone simulation mode on an iPad.

Comment: Did you add the pictures and submit for approval with your build? Look at AppStore connect, scroll all the way to the bottom of the in app purchase.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73628614/cant-add-first-auto-renewable-subscription-to-new-app-version/73628670#73628670

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have found the issue, but I'm not sure how to address it. I've updated my post.

Comment: This is not a programming problem but a human engineering problem. You need to get them to test on an iPhone or you need to add an iPhone implementation.

Comment: On the other hand, you say "when we try to fetch products on an iPad" but it looks to me like you're not really testing what a user would experience; you're in Sandbox Mode.

Comment: To clarify, the problem is in production. When an app is published for iPhones only, Apple will allow users to download the app to iPads in iPhone simulations mode, and developers can't prevent that. In those circumstances, the App Store will throw an error when the app tries to fetch products (doesn't matter if via StoreKit, RevenueCat or any other means). Apple will return an error that the platform is not supported by any products. If you have a hard paywall on an iPhone only app, you may have iPad users downloading the app and getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

So far, there doesn't seem to be a way around this issue. However, Apple's review team eventually approved our app after some explaining.

Note that if you have an iPhone only app, iPad users will be able to download it, but they will not be able to fetch products / subscriptions from the App Store and get past the paywall.

As of March 2024 there's no reliable way to detect if a user is in iPhone simulation mode on an iPad.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).